# Can I change wdio.conf capabilities dynamically based on what it block I'm running?

Tags: webdriver.io

I have a test suite where certain it blocks require a different set of capabilities
I want to be able to change the **args** as my tests execute

```
capabilities: {
    myChromeBrowser: {
        capabilities: {
            'browserName': 'chrome',
            'goog:chromeOptions': {
                args: ['--headless', '--disable-gpu', '--window-size=1920x1080','--no-sandbox', '--use-fake-ui-for-media-stream', '--use-fake-device-for-media-stream' ]
            }
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was solved through multiremote. You can define different objects in multiremote capabilities in wdio.conf files and then use them as you wish.

```
    capabilities: {
        myChromeBrowser: {
            capabilities: {
                'browserName': 'chrome',
                'goog:chromeOptions': {
                    args: [
                    '--headless', '--disable-gpu', 
                    '--window-size=1920x1080',
                    '--no-sandbox', 
                    '--use-fake-ui-for-media-stream', 
                    '--use-fake-device-for-media-stream' ]
                }
            }
        },
    
        chromeDisablePerm: {
            capabilities: {
                'browserName': 'chrome',
                'goog:chromeOptions': {
                    args: [
                        '--headless', 
                        '--disable-gpu',
                        '--window-size=1920x1080',
                            '--deny-permission-prompts',
                    
                ]
                }
            }
    
        },
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  console.log(browser.capabilities)
```

Gives the browser capabilities currently set try changing it

```
    browser.capabilities = {new}
```

You can access the entire config file as:

```
   console.log(browser.config)
```

Comment: You can add that as answer and accept it